# Bochner Space "basic properties" (Reference Request)

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

I'm looking for references to what I believe to be "basic properties" of Bochner Space of the type
$$L^p(\Omega; X),$$
where $X$ is a Banach space and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is an opened and bounded subset.

What I mean by basic properties are the results about $L^p(\Omega; X)$ being Banach, reflexive, separable... All the books that I found use this results (some of then even enunciate it), but never prove.

Can somebody save me? :)

Comment: I think you should be able to find your answers in the book "Vector Measures" from Diestel and Uhl. For $\Omega=(0,T)$ you can probably find more references, e.g. "Nonlinear Functional Analysis II/A" from Zeidler, or if you speak German, then the book from Gajewski is great.